# Why is JSON return showing open curly bracket instead of data?

Tags: php, json

So I'm returning the data from twitter, and for some reason I cannot return the count data, all it returns when I echo it is the open curly bracket.. here is how I am trying to echo it.

```
"statuses": [],
"search_metadata": {
    "completed_in": 0.008,
    "max_id": 668543797022826500,
    "max_id_str": "668543797022826503",
    "query": "URL",
    "refresh_url": "URL",
    "count": 15,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
}
```

That is what the code below returns.. all I am trying to do is echo the `count` data but it doesn't.. all it prints instead of the `15` is `{`

```
$counter    = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=".$this->url );
$ajsn       = json_encode($counter);

echo $ajsn['search_metadata']['count'];
```

Could anyone explain to me why this isn't printing?

Comment: You should consider using `json_decode($counter)`, if you want to access your data. `json_encode` returns a JSON-string from an PHP-Array or Object, `json_decode` will convert a JSON-string to a PHP-Structure.

Comment: you seem to think you have an array, when you don't

Comment: Shouldn't we be using echo $ajsn['search_metadata.count'] or something like that? As the `search_metadata` is an object and not an array ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$ajsn = json_decode($counter, true);
echo $ajsn['search_metadata']['count'];
```

Comment: I've tried json_decode, I figured it was incorrect because it returns empty, haven't been able to understand why either. Although in any other situation that would be correct.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 could you upload a pastebin with exactly what twitter is spitting out?

Comment: As I said, not much.. it's either blank or with the bracket.. http://pastebin.com/frUMV0k9

Comment: So apparently I had to echo it the following way: echo $counter->search_metadata->count;

Comment: @iBrazilian2 ah yes, that's what the second parameter of `json_decode` is. By default it doesn't return an associative array unless you pass a second parameter of `true`